# Finding the order of $N_G(H)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have this question:

For a group $G=A_5$ and $H=$ $\langle(12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle$ , prove that $(123)\in N_G(H)$ and hence deduce the order of $N_G(H)$.

$A_5$ is defined to be the alternating group and $N_G(H)=\{g\in G :H^g=H \}$, where $H^g=\{g^{-1}hg:h\in H\}$

I have managed to prove that $(123)\in N_G(H)$ simply by calculating $H^{(123)}$ and verifying. I do not know to calculate the order of $N_G(H)$ though, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have obtained a lower bound on the order of $N_G(H)$ (which is?...). But you also know that $A_5$ is simple, and that will give you upper bounds on the size of $N_G(H)$, and of any proper subgroup, for that matter. Why is $N_G(H)$ a proper subgroup?

Comment: I can't say I understand. $A_5$ is simple which would mean the only normal subgroups of G are $\{1\}$ and $G$ itself. This would mean that the upper bound on the size of $N_G(H)$ is $|A_5|$?

Comment: What would that tell you about $H$ if $N_G(H)=G$?

Comment: Could you please write the solution if you're willing? I'm really finding this topic hard and have tried my best to find a solution and can't find any similar examples.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out an alternative way.